# Beakerx - 'validating problems found: beakerx/tree beakerx/extension'

Tags: jupyter-lab, beaker-notebook, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

Trying to get beakerx working with JupyterLab using pipenv.

**Install**

```
$ pipenv install beakerx
$ beakerx install

Installing /Users/layne/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/envs/biodb-py3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/beakerx/static -> beakerx
- Validating: problems found:
   X  require: /Users/layne/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/envs/biodb-py3.7.3/share/jupyter/nbextensions/beakerx/tree.js
  OK section: tree
Full spec: {'section': 'tree', 'src': 'static', 'dest': 'beakerx', 'require': 'beakerx/tree'}
Installing /Users/layne/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/envs/biodb-py3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/beakerx/static -> beakerx
- Validating: problems found:
   X  require: /Users/layne/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/envs/biodb-py3.7.3/share/jupyter/nbextensions/beakerx/extension.js
  OK section: notebook
```

**Checking what extensions are enabled**

```
$ jupyter nbextension list

  notebook section
      ipyvolume/extension  enabled
      - Validating: OK
      jupyter-webrtc/extension  enabled
      - Validating: OK
      jupyter-datawidgets/extension  enabled
      - Validating: OK
      jupyter-matplotlib/extension  enabled
      - Validating: OK
      jupyter-threejs/extension  enabled
      - Validating: OK
      jupyter-js-widgets/extension  enabled
      - Validating: OK
      beakerx/extension  enabled
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X beakerx/extension

    tree section
      beakerx/tree  enabled
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X beakerx/tree
```

**Saw this attempt to enable in a few posts.**

```
$ jupyter nbextension enable beakerx --py --sys-prefix


Enabling tree extension beakerx/tree...
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X beakerx/tree
Enabling notebook extension beakerx/extension...
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X beakerx/extension
```

As you can see, `beakerx/tree` and `beakerx/extension` appear not to be installed.

I've been trying different combinations of `jupyter labextension install beakerx/...`

**Show npm packages**

```
npm list
biodb@1.0.0 /Users/layne/Desktop/BioDB
└── beakerx-jupyterlab@1.4.1
```

Comment: SOLVED with `beakerx uninstall` and `beakerx install`